# TemplateView not working in django get_absolute_url

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views

I have one `report` app that manages all flagging of inappropriate content on my project. A member `reporter` can report another member `reported` for posting inappropriate content. Everything works fine and the report object is created, however it does not redirect to the thanks page in the end. but gets back to the same form page. What is highly strange is that when I paste `http://127.0.0.1:8000/report/thanks/` in the address bar I surprisingly see the form page. usually the report page would have the url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/report/Amanda/` What exactly is going wrong here.

Below are my **models.py**

```
class Report(models.Model):
    reporter = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='reporting_members')
    reported = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='reported_members')
    report_url = models.URLField(max_length=2000, blank=True, null=True)
    reported_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    reporting_choices = (
        ('1', 'The images posted by this user are not relevant to the Post),
        ('2', 'Rude or abusive content, The words chosen by the user are inappropriate'),
        ('3', 'This user is asking me to change my review in return for favor '),
        ('4', 'Other'),
    )
    reason_to_report = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=reporting_choices)
    reason = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} is reporting {} for {}'.format(self.reporter, self.reported, self.reason_to_report)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('report:thanks')
```

Below are my **views.py**

```
class ReportCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Report
    fields = ('reason_to_report', 'reason')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.reporter = self.request.user
        form.instance.reported = User.objects.get(username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
        next = self.request.POST.get('next')
        form.instance.report_url = next
        super().form_valid(form)
        return redirect('report:thanks')




class ThanksView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'report/thanks.html'
```

Below is my **urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<username>[-\w]+)/$', views.ReportCreateView.as_view(), name='report_user'),
    url(r'^thanks/$', views.ThanksView.as_view(), name='thanks'),

]
```

below is the **template** for my Report form

```
<form action="" method="post" >
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% bootstrap_form form %}
      <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ request.META.HTTP_REFERER }}">    
      <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" />
      <a href="{% url 'home' %}">
         <button class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
      </a>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"thanks"` is a matching string for your username regex. Django always takes the first pattern that matches, so will route to the reportcreate view.

Swap the order of your URL patterns.

Comment: how exactly do you mean `url(r'^thanks_you_for_reporting/$', views.ThanksView.as_view(), name='thanks'),`

Comment: Er, no.  I said to swap the order, so that the "thanks" pattern comes before the "report_user" one.,

Comment: that worked is there any docs where I can get more info on this. I never knew the ordering of the URS actually mattered

Comment: It's all in the [URL dispatcher docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request). Note particularly the line "Django runs through each URL pattern, in order, and stops at the first one that matches the requested URL".